# tmux: trying to bind utf8 key

Tags: tmux, utf-8, bind, xbindkeys

I'm using tmux 1.6 with konsole on Fedora 17 i686.

I have an azerty keyboard (with accentued chars), and I want ton bind 'ù' key.

I made the following ~/.tmux.conf:

```
setw -g utf8 on
bind-key ù split-window -h
```

But, when I run tmux I have the following error:

```
/home/glines/.tmux.conf: 2: unknown key: ù
```

Is there a way to bind this key?

For your help,
Thanks by advance.

Comment: The selected answer is outdated. Tmux does support UTF-8 binding now. See the other answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, *tmux* only supports single 8-bit values in its key bindings.

If you were using a (fixed length) 8-bit encoding (e.g. ISO 8859-1, ISO 8859-15, etc.), then the binding should have worked. If you are using UTF-8, however, your ù (U+00F9) is encoded as two bytes (C3 B9), and *tmux* rejects it as a unknown key name (if a key is longer than a single byte (after stripping its modifier prefixes), it is processed as the name of a special key e.g. `F1`, `PageUp`, `KP0`, etc.).

---

Though, if you are desperate there is a gross hack that you could try:

```
tmux bind-key -r $(printf '\303') display 'c3 prefix binding hack' \; \
     bind-key -r $(printf '\271') split-window -h
```

This abuses the “repeat” binding functionality by using it to stay in “prefix mode” while basically ignoring the first byte of the UTF-8 encoding of ù (hex C3 B9, octal 303 271).

The first byte of ù (octal 303) is bound to a dummy command, and the second byte (octal 271) is bound to the target command. This requires that you must not have set the *tmux* `repeat-time` option to zero (to disable repeating), and has a side effect of leaving *tmux* in its repeat mode for `repeat-time` milliseconds (defaults to 500ms) after you have typed <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>ù</kbd> (this side effect will usually only be noticeable if you immediately type an arrow key (with or without <kbd>Control</kbd> or <kbd>Meta</kbd>) after <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>ù</kbd>—those keys are the only default bindings that are “repeatable”).

The above example uses the `printf` shell command to generate the required bytes, but this will not work in your `.tmux.conf`. If you were running *tmux* 1.7, you could write it like this (in your `.tmux.conf`):

```
bind-key -r 0xC3 display 'c3 prefix binding hack'
bind-key -r 0xB9 split-window -h
```

However, this hex key syntax does not work in *tmux* 1.6. So, you either need to arrange for the raw bytes to be directly in the file (your text editor may fight you on this, and it is easy to make a mistake), or use a shell to assist you:

```
run-shell "tmux bind-key -r $(printf '\\303') display 'c3 prefix binding hack' \\; bind-key -r $(printf '\\271') split-window -h"
```

Note: `run-shell` runs its command asynchronously, so the bindings may not be available immediately after your first session starts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the run-shell part doesn't work but I will update tmux soon.

Comment: The problem with the `run-shell` command may have been that I used `~/bin/tmux` instead of plain `tmux` (I have edited the answer; I also dug up a 1.6 binary and verified that it worked with it in a separate server instance).

Comment: So what is the syntax if I want to bind `split-window -h` on <kbd>Prefix</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>ù</kbd>?

Answer (score 3):

Since tmux 2.3 dynamic rebinding as explained by Chris Johnsen is no longer necassary and does not even work.
To bind any UTF-8 character just use it's unicode value in `0x` notation.

## Example

Let's say you want to bind <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>ě</kbd> (small E with caron) to window 2.

First you need to find out unicode value of `ě` (note that this is defferent from UTF-8 code sequence).

You can use e.g. `python3` to convert UTF-8 character to it's unicode value:

```
$ python3
>>> hex(ord('ě'))
'0x11b'
```

Now when you know unicode value of `ě` is `0x011B` simply add this line to your tmux config file:

```
bind-key 0x011B select-window -t 2
```