# Bind Tmux prefix to an unicode character?

Tags: tmux, unicode, prefix

I'd like to bind the Tmux prefix to the unicode character `` (while also keeping `C-b`).

I'we tried putting the following in my `~/.tmux.conf`, but none of theese works

`set -g prefix M-$
bind M-$ send-prefix`

`set -g prefix 
bind  send-prefix`

`set -g prefix ""
bind "" send-prefix`

I'm on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3, using a Danish keyboard layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tmux only binds "single" characters (8-bit) plus a few special keys which can be found in the terminal database.

The [manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1) is a little vague:

> tmux allows a command to be bound to most keys, with or without a prefix key. When specifying keys, most represent themselves (for example ‘A’ to ‘Z’). Ctrl keys may be prefixed with ‘C-’ or ‘^’, and Alt (meta) with ‘M-’. In addition, the following special key names are accepted: Up, Down, Left, Right, BSpace, BTab, DC (Delete), End, Enter, Escape, F1 to F12, Home, IC (Insert), NPage/PageDown/PgDn, PPage/PageUp/PgUp, Space, and Tab.

However, this has been discussed before (along with the *ctrl* and *alt* modifiers):

- *[tmux: trying to bind utf8 key](https://superuser.com/questions/517836/tmux-trying-to-bind-utf8-key)*
- *[How do I bind the tmux prefix to a Super?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/how-do-i-bind-the-tmux-prefix-to-a-super)*

Comment: Arh yearh, I found theese, just hoped in vain that something had changed since 2012 :( But thank you for the quick reply anyway.